# How to exclude points from a set quickly

Tags: python, performance

I have a large list of pairs of pairs of integers.  For example

```
pairs = [((3, 5), (5, 5)), ((1, 1), (2, 5)), ((5, 1), (4, 3))]
```

I also have a large list of pairs of integers. For example,

```
nums = [(2, 5), (4, 2), (5, 2)]
```

I would like to remove from pairs any pair that has any pair in nums. For example,

```
nums = set(nums)
pairs = [((x1,y1),(x2,y2)) for ((x1,y1),(x2,y2)) in pairs if  not (set([(x1,y1),(x2,y2)]) & nums)]
```

This gives

```
[((3, 5), (5, 5)), ((5, 1), (4, 3))]
```

The problem is that this is very slow when pairs and nums are large.  How can you speed this up?

Example slow input:

```
import random
nums = [(random.randint(1,50000),random.randint(1,50000)) for i in xrange(1000000)]
pairs = [((random.randint(1,50000),random.randint(1,50000)), (random.randint(1,50000),random.randint(1,50000))) for i in xrange(8000000)]
```

Comment: How large is your pair list and num list and what is reasonable amount of time that you want to fit in?

Comment: @Artur My question was over simplified. I have updated it with a more accurate version that shows how slow it is.

Comment: do you need to re construct pairs list, or just iterate over filtering generator, I'm pretty sure that it's the bottleneck

Comment: @alko Just iterate over it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be the fastest

```
nums=set(nums)
pairs= filter(nums.isdisjoint, pairs)
```

Here are the times:

```
In [1]: import random

In [2]: pairs=[(random.randint(0,50),random.randint(0,50)) for i in range (1000)]

In [3]: nums=[random.randint(0,1000) for i in range(500)]

In [4]: numset=set(nums)

In [5]: %timeit [(x,y) for (x,y) in pairs if not (set([x,y]) & numset)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 746 us per loop

In [6]: %timeit [(x,y) for (x,y) in pairs if x not in numset and y not in numset]
10000 loops, best of 3: 145 us per loop    

In [7]: %timeit filter(numset.isdisjoint, pairs)
10000 loops, best of 3: 95.1 us per loop
```

Comment: Aiaiai! how on earth did I miss that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: that depends, on my machine second measured approach is fastest

Comment: filter is fastest for me and a lot faster than what I had. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion would be to make the `nums` a set, so that the lookups will be faster.

```
pairs = [(1,2),(2,3),(7,2)]
nums = {3,7} # Its a set now
print [(first, second) for first, second in pairs if first not in nums and second not in nums]
```

**Output**

```
[(1, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be some solution you may measure

```
def rm_pairs(pairs, nums):
    cursor = 0
    while True:
        if cursor == len(pairs):
            break
        #print cursor
        p = pairs[cursor]
        for n in nums:
            if n in p:
                pairs.pop(cursor)
                cursor = 0
                break
        cursor += 1
```